# Why is dimethylmercury more toxic (to animal life) than methylmercury or ethylmercury?

Tags: organic-chemistry, toxicity

It's obviously a two step process to reduce dimethylmercury to the less harmful inorganic form.

Is neuronal uptake also enhanced due to lipophilicity? Is there some other mechanism of toxicity I'm overlooking?

Comment: Hmm what are your sources? There are studies that show that this is not the case.